# CoreStore creating object and return it in success

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift5, corestore

I use this code to create an object:

```
CoreStore.perform(
            asynchronous: { (transaction) -> Void in
                let summary = transaction.create(Into<SummaryEntity>())

        },
            completion: { _ in }
        )
```

In completion I would like to return back just created summary object.

How to do this?

I did something like that, but not sure for what we need a lot of unwraps and `fetchExisting` function

```
CoreStore.perform(
            asynchronous: { (transaction) -> Routine? in

                let routine = try! transaction.importUniqueObject(
                    Into<Routine>(),
                    source: routineDictionary)

                return routine
        },
            success: { (transactionRoutine) in

                guard let unwrappedTransactionRoutine = transactionRoutine else {
                    return
                }

                let routine = CoreStore.fetchExisting(unwrappedTransactionRoutine)

                guard let unwrappedRoutine = routine else {
                    return
                }

                completion(.data(unwrappedRoutine))
        },
            failure: { (error) in
                // ...
        }
        )
```

This is an error of unwrapping from `fetchExisting`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking as your examples are completely different.

If you want to create an object, you would do the same as for importing.
transaction.create does not return an optional, so just have your closure in the first one return the object:

```
CoreStore.perform(asynchronous: { (transaction) -> SummaryEntity in
    let summary = transaction.create(Into<SummaryEntity>())
    return summary
}, success: { (summary) in
    let fetchedSummary = CoreStore.fetchExisting(summary)
    completion(.data(fetchedSummary))
}, failure: { (error) in
    // ...
})
```

Comment: ok thanks! looks like we still need to unwrap fetchedSummary. Am I right that we need to use `CoreStore.fetchExisting` to get `NSManagedObject` from the main read only context and `success: { (summary) in` returns `NSManagedObject` from background context?

Comment: Yes correct, thats my observation too that the returned item is from the background context. So you have to do fetchExisting. I don't know why you need to unwrap it though, as fetchExisting does not return an optional.

Comment: I've added an image with optional compile error. thanks for help!

Comment: Ok, I see ... I always used arrays, they are indeed nonoptional but the single fetch returns optional. Then you would need to do an if let to unwrap and otherwise execute the completion(.error....) type.